# php with google app engine or amazon-ec2

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ec2

What is better to code with php in google app engine or in amazon-ec2.
I think it is better in amazon-ec2 because they support datastore with php and google app engine doesn't, what do you think ?

Comment: Question is too broad and i dont know where you got that appengine php doesnt support datastore.

Comment: actually if you look at the storing data section in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/?hl=iw you will notice that app engine php support just cloud sql and cloud storage ! if it is support datastroe api so why there no documentation?

Comment: Yes it does support datastore through another new api cloud datastore (not cloud storage).  Google on how to use it from php. In any case you can't at all compare the appengine datastore with amazon dynamo db which is an extremely simple nosql.

Comment: Btw sorry about my inital assumption. I did think that the regular appengine datastore was available in php. The other one (cloud datastore) is new and independent from appengine (could use it from compute engine etc) but based on the same tech.

Comment: so, is there a library that i could use to connect my app engine(with php) to cloud datastore , i would be happy to receive a link !

Comment: did you try googling? if you type "cloud datastore from php" in google, the first link is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While its not possible to access the appengine datastore, google has a new preview service for "cloud datastore", google "cloud datastore from php" and you will see how to use it.
You really cant compare AWS with appengine as one requires managing servers and scalability manually and their noSQL solution (dynamoDB) is a joke compared to google's datastore, for example in dynamoDB you must provision your writes beforehand and even if you are all day changing provisioning, it takes sometimes hours to propagate the new setting.

Comment: In my experience, Datastore was much more limiting than DynamoDB: Datastore reads have eventual consistency, which is acceptable sometimes, but very often you need strong consistency. The only way to support strong consistency is by [putting related data in the same entity group](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) which limits writes to that group to 1 write/second! Very limiting for a scalable system like AppEngine.

Comment: Yes strong writes complicate things. But dynamodb doesnt scale. You have to manually provision the writes per second as your service grows/shrinks which is certainly does not autoscale.

Comment: There are tools to autoscale DynamoDB, look at [this AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/auto-scale-dynamodb-with-dynamic-dynamodb/)

Answer (score 0):

I had never use Google App Engine, but several times AWS systems, and sure, as AWS EC2 could be used as Linux Server Instance, I recommend you that provider. And coz' it seems that you use PHP, they have strong API for this langage. Have fun with AWS.

Comment: thank you for your fast response, but does amazon provide a platform or infrastructure, so google app engine is platform so i just deploy my code without care about the operating system or any updates .

Comment: If you dont know about appengine how can you possibly answer this?